# how to combine these 2 queries to 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to add a commaseperated column with a list of product categorynames for that product. This is my datamodel:
[image]

I got all the productdetails in this query:

```
select d.name as 'Dealer Name',c.commissionamount as 'Commission Amount',c.createddate as 'Commission Created Date' ,p.name as 'Product Name'
from commission c
join dealer d 
on d.dealerid=c.dealerid
join product p on c.productid=p.productid
join productcategorymapping pcm on p.ProductId=pcm.ProductId
join ProductCategory pc on pc.ProductCategoryId=pcm.ProductCategoryId
```

I just want to add the csv column for each product with this query , I just dont know how to join the 2:

```
select stuff((
SELECT ',' + pc.Name
FROM ProductCategory pc
join ProductCategoryMapping pcm on pcm.ProductCategoryId=pc.ProductCategoryId
join Product p1 on p1.ProductId=pcm.ProductId
and p1.ProductId=1
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'');
```

It says productId=1 but this is where it needs to be joined to the other query.
So the result would be something like:

```
DealerName  | Amount |date|product Name|csv
TestDealer1 | 105.25 |..  |ProdA       |CatA,CatC,CatF
```

I also created a sqlfiddle for this:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d574e/4

Comment: +1 for a very well presented question along with sql fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..

```
select
       d.name             AS [Dealer Name]
      ,c.commissionamount AS [Commission Amount]
      ,c.createddate      AS [Commission Created Date] 
      ,p.name             AS [Product Name]
      ,stuff((SELECT ', ' + pcci.Name
              FROM ProductCategory pcci
              join ProductCategoryMapping pcmi 
              on pcmi.ProductCategoryId=pcci.ProductCategoryId
              join Product p1i 
              on p1i.ProductId=pcmi.ProductId
              WHERE p1i.ProductId = p.productid
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'')
                           AS [CSV]

from commission c join dealer d 
on d.dealerid=c.dealerid
join product p 
on c.productid=p.productid;
```

### [`Working SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d574e/3)

Comment: this returns testdealer1 3 times, look at the top query in the fiddle

Comment: @user603007 Have a look now I have updated my answer.

Comment: M.ALi thanks for the answer, do you think the db design for this schema is optimized for performance ? where can I change it?

Comment: @user603007 It is very difficult to say if a design is fit for performance or not without knowing about the whole lot of stuff about the database, application requirements etc. Just read about the Normalization rules for Database and try to get your database at least to 3rd normal form. At first glance it looks ok. Performance of a database is dependant on many factor, database design is just one. anyway if the answer helped you please accept it. and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done just by combining the two in the Select statements like:

```
select DISTINCT d.name as 'Dealer Name',
c.commissionamount as 'Commission Amount',
c.createddate as 'Commission Created Date' ,
p.name as 'Product Name',
stuff((
SELECT ',' + pc.Name
FROM ProductCategory pc
join ProductCategoryMapping pcm on pcm.ProductCategoryId=pc.ProductCategoryId
join Product p1 on p1.ProductId=pcm.ProductId
and p1.ProductId=1
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as reqCol
from commission c
join dealer d 
on d.dealerid=c.dealerid
join product p 
on c.productid=p.productid
join productcategorymapping pcm 
on p.ProductId=pcm.ProductId
join ProductCategory pc 
on pc.ProductCategoryId=pcm.ProductCategoryId;
```

Check out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d574e/12

Comment: should the ReqCol value for TestDealer2 not be CatB?